# How can I get Intellisense to show range based for snipped?

Tags: visual-studio, c++, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2019, when we enter "for" in the editor, *Intellisense* suggests "[for each](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=vs-2019)" snippet,

```
for each (object var in collection_to_loop)
{
}
```

which is not recommended. And it reports error for the code made by itself. It should be [range based for statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/range-based-for-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019) using colon that *Intellisense* suggests:

```
for (object var : collection_to_loop)
{
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA5P9.png) is screen shot when I enter "for" in the Visual Studio 2019.

I don't want to do unnecessary typing every for loop.

Is it possible that we get *Intellisense* to suggest range based for statement using colon?

Comment: Provide some sample code and points the intellisense that you want.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks for your comment. I added code and screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question but I found it. It can be found using "rfor" and it produces the code:

```
    for (auto &i : v) {  

    }
```